# ansible-playbook consistenly fails as gathering facts phase

Tags: ansible

I've been tasked with implementing some new ansible playbooks as I'm the only one here with any experience with a configuration tool. Problem for me is that I've only ever used puppet, not ansible. No matter what I write for ansible, however, I constantly get:

> TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************
> fatal: [server1.example.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the connection plugin 'heck' was not found"}
> fatal: [server2.example.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the connection plugin 'heck' was not found"}

Web searches for this error have been fruitless, but at first I thought I might have a problem with my ssh keys to these servers. Testing those showed that I can login with ssh without a password, however. So, now I'm stuck.

Anybody have thoughts on resolving this?

Comment: There's an error message to guide you: "the connection plugin 'heck' was not found". Why do you override default `ssh` plugin?

Comment: I didn't setup this ansible-server, so I didn't know that someone changed the default plugin. What bothers me more is that the guy who did setup this server can successfully run most of the yaml I created. I just can't tell what's different between our two laptops.

Comment: Can you share the contents of your inventory file or your ansible.cfg? Specifically, the code that defines what connection plugin ("heck") to use.

Comment: From what I can see the inventory file only contains a group tag and a pair of servers under it. I haven't been able to find where this connection plugin is defined.

Answer (score 25):

I also got this error:

> FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the connection plugin 'heck' was not found"}

My problem was I was trying to run in check mode but left off a "-" in my command.

I did this:

```
ansible-playbook foo.yml -check
```

instead of this:

```
ansible-playbook foo.yml --check
```

By leaving off the 2nd `-`, `ansible-playbook` thought I was using the connection option (with `heck` as the value...).

Comment: For me, adding the two "--" made it work instead of one on RHEL 8. Idk why...

Comment: @ParthPatel because `--check` (double dash) means "run in check mode" while `-check` (single dash) means "use a custom connection plugin named `heck`" (same as `-c heck`). See `ansible-playbook --help`

Answer (score -2):

I finally got everything working, and I believe the problem was due to my git environment, which is where I was running the playbook. I ended up uninstalling git and reinstalling it, and now everything runs OK. I saw the git issue when I could not commit any file change on either the server or my laptop. Since the laptop had been working, I performed the reinstall there, and that "fixed" the server.